# Kubectl kustomize edit can't find kustomization.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kustomize

I am trying to run kustomize command in a directory which has an overlay `kustomization.yaml`

When I run `kubectl kustomize edit set namespace test` in that dir, I get

```
error: specify one path to kustomization.yaml
```

Whilst when I run `kustomize edit set namespace test`, it works.

So the problem is when I run use kustomize from kubectl.

Kubectl version is v1.24.2, which has Kustomize Version: v4.5.4

and separately installed Kustomize binary version is v4.5.5

Comment: I feel that `kubectl kustomize` doesn't include all commands of `kustomize` but i didn't find any source/documentation confirming this

Answer (score 2):

I suspect `kubectl kustomize` doesn't support sub commands. You should instead create your `kustomization.yaml` file and simply run `kubectl kustomize` to generate your manifests. If I recall correctly, until a couple of years ago, the `kustomize` project was available as a `go module` which allowed the `kubectl` developers to include it in their projects and make use of its capabilities. Later, it was moved to the state of being a stand-alone project and no longer offered as a module for developers, and there was no motive to duplicate the efforts by reimplementing the `kustomize` functionality in programs. Perhaps that's why it was never fully integrated into `kubectl` and many other projects that try to use it.

Notice that the error says specify ***one*** path to `kustomization.yaml`. This means the command is interpreting your sub command as a path.

You san simply provide this as:

```
kubectl kustomize <dir of kustomization.yaml>
```

You can read more about the command and supported flags [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#kustomize).

> Note that if you are running `kustomize` on a directory structure, you will require a `kustomization.yaml` file in *every subdir*.

Comment: So I am already in the overlay directory which has `kustomization.yaml` and then running `kubectl kustomize`. The linked document says "If DIR is omitted, '.' is assumed.", then why it's not honoring it.

whilst at the same time `kustomize` works.

Comment: Does this directory have any other directories in it?

Comment: no, Just `kustomization.yaml` and a json file

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, I also suspect that this might be the case. Though I didn't find any source to confirm this

Comment: [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/) is a docs reference that talks about this. THis should confirm it, what other source are you looking for? These are updated official docs for `kubectl kustomize`.